# Only top row of DataGridView updating?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that I'm populating from a list. The function that edits this list is called `LoadCollectionData()'`. Extra rows get added to the list just fine, and the relevant data pertaining to that row populates when the row is added.

The problem is that later on when other data is being changed that'd alter what's displayed on the datagrid, only the top row continues to update, all of the others remain the same.

Here's the code for the method:

```
    public bool haschanged = false;

    public class KeywordDensity
    {
        public bool included { get; set; }
        public string keyword { get; set; }
        public string occurences { get; set; }
        public string density { get; set; }
    }

    public int WordCount(string txtToCount)
    {
        string pattern = "\\w+";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        int CountedWords = regex.Matches(txtToCount).Count;

        return CountedWords;
    }

    public int KeywordCount(string txtToCount, string pattern)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        int CountedWords = regex.Matches(txtToCount).Count;

        return CountedWords;
    }


    public List<KeywordDensity> LoadCollectionData()
    {
        string thearticle = txtArticle.Text.ToLower();
        string keywordslower = txtKeywords.Text.ToLower();
        string[] keywordsarray = keywordslower.Split('\r');
        List<KeywordDensity> lsikeywords = new List<KeywordDensity>();
        bool isincluded = false;
        double keywordcount = 0;
        double wordcount = WordCount(thearticle);
        double thedensity = 0;



        foreach (string s in keywordsarray)
        {

            if (s != "")
            {
                keywordcount = KeywordCount(thearticle, s);
                thedensity = keywordcount / wordcount;
                thedensity = Math.Round(thedensity, 4) * 100;


                if (thearticle.Contains(s))
                {
                    isincluded = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    isincluded = false;
                }


                lsikeywords.Add(new KeywordDensity()
                {
                    included = isincluded,
                    keyword = s,
                    occurences = keywordcount.ToString(),
                    density = thedensity.ToString() + "%"
                });

            }

        }

        return lsikeywords;
    }

    private void txtArticle_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (haschanged == false)
            haschanged = true;

        lblWordCountNum.Text = WordCount(txtArticle.Text).ToString();

        dataGrid.DataSource = LoadCollectionData();

    }

    private void dataGrid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int cursorpos = 0;
        string copied = "";

        if (dataGrid.CurrentCellAddress.X == 1) //Only grab content if the "Keyword" column has been clicked on
            copied = " " + dataGrid.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() + " ";

        cursorpos = txtArticle.SelectionStart;
        txtArticle.Text = txtArticle.Text.Insert(cursorpos, copied);
    }
```

What's even more odd, **is that when I click on any of the rows, then they immediately update**. However, unless the row is clicked on (unless it's the top one) it doesn't update.

Because of this, I suspect there may be some property I need to set on the dataGrid itself, or I need to somehow tell each row to refresh through code.

What's the dealio?

**EDIT**: It appears that the only reason that the cell that's clicked on updates is because I actively grab content from the cell. I commented out the code below and it stopped updating even when clicked on. It then would only update the top row's values and that's it.

Code:

```
//Moved above in EDIT 3
```

**EDIT 2:** Here's the class declaration for KeywordDensity:

```
//Moved above in EDIT 3
```

**EDIT 3**: Posted whole schebang.

Comment: How are you assigning the datasource to the grid

Comment: Yes. When the text is changed in my main textbox I call: dataGrid.Datasource = LoadCollectionData();

Comment: ok looks like we need to see the whole code now.. can you show it...

Comment: Alrighty, posted damn near the whole project. If there were a way to post the properties of the DataGridView I'd do that too, although I've removed the current one and tried the code with a brand new one that hasn't been altered in any way from default and it still did the same thing. Thanks Shekhar_Pro!

Comment: Interesting.. In this post I found on the MSDN forum it mentions an issue with a row of the DataGridView being selected interfering with his update. - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/winformsdatacontrols/thread/53E22C66-AA68-4165-A244-2FCEFDAC896E - I've noticed that as soon as I start typing the top row of the DataGridView gets selected even though it doesn't have focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code slightly, try this code.

```
string[] keywordsarray = keywordslower.Split
    (new char[] {'\r','\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `Invalidate()` the control to trigger a repaint.

Comment: Tried that. Unfortunately it didn't work for me. I called the following to attempt it: dataGrid.DataSource = LoadCollectionData();
            dataGrid.Invalidate();

Comment: Damn. dataGrid.Refresh(); doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 0):

call the [`DataBind()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) method of the datagrid. That should do.

**Update**

There's a **[ResetBindings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings.aspx)** in that case.

Comment: There is no DataBind method. I'm using a DataGridView, not a GridView.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't seem to have that method either. I'm using VS 2010 if that makes any difference. Is it perhaps some issue with the new rows not being "committed" or something? I've no idea if that's even possible, but I just find it extremely odd that they all start to update after I click on each one and that code I included above grabs the value out of the cell clicked. This problem is baffling.   Thanks for the insta-response though!

Comment: try setting a break point on the click event of the grid a see what is happening behind...or show us the call stack

Comment: All the CallStack shows is that there was a MouseUp event when I set a breakpoint on either the portion of code where the string is copied from the cell value, or on the event itself..